# Got react context as JSON but can't really access its parts

Tags: json, reactjs, react-context

I get a context from a react component via useContext:

```
const [getDrinksData, setDrinksData] = useContext(DrinksContext)
```

and can access e.g.
`getDrinksData.length`: 193 or

`JSON.stringify(getDrinksData)`:   `[{"country":"Afghanistan","beer_servings":"0","spirit_servings":"0","wine_servings":"0","total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":"0.0"},{"country":"Albania","beer_servings":"89","spirit_servings":"132","wine_servings":"54","total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":"4.9"},{"country":"Algeria","beer_servings":"25","spirit_servings":"0","wine_servings":"14","total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":"0.7"},{"country":"Andorra","beer_servings":"245","spirit_servings":"138","wine_servings":"312","total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":"12.4"}, ...`

or even

`JSON.stringify(getDrinksData[0])`:

```
{"country":"Afghanistan","beer_servings":"0","spirit_servings":"0","wine_servings":"0","total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":"0.0"}
```

but if I try to access

```
getDrinksData[0].country
```

I get an error that getDrinksData[0] is not defined.

If I use

```
getDrinksData.map((drinks,index) => (<p key={index}>{drinks.country} {drinks.beer_servings} {drinks.spirit_servings} {drinks.wine_servings} {drinks.total_litres_of_pure_alcohol}</p>))
```

it works.
Can anybody explain this or help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Thomas

Comment: Everything seems fine, double-check your typo in your code to be sure.

Comment: I don't see any typo.

<p>Land: {JSON.stringify(getDrinksData)}</p>
<p>Length: {JSON.stringify(getDrinksData.length)}</p>
<p>element: {JSON.stringify(getDrinksData[0])}</p>
<p>element: {JSON.stringify(getDrinksData[0].country)}</p>

From the upper 4 lines 3 work but everytime I try the last one
I get the error:

TypeError: getDrinksData[0] is undefined

And this makes no sense to me.